# In PHP, is it possible to store multiple files within any type of container/archive?

Tags: php

### The problem

We have approximately 5,500,000 small image files in 1000 different sub-categories, which as worked great until now. Unfortunately, our web host has some weird limitation to their server structure, that makes our current setup cause errors in their system.

They've now asked us to change our structure by limiting the total number of files to ~500,000, and I'm looking for a simple solution. The web host is great in other ways - has great support, great availability, cheap, etc., which makes us want to stay there. At least for now.

### The question

Is it possible to, in some way, contain multiple files - all < 600 kB - in any type of container or archive, which is easily accessible using PHP?

#### More or less stupid ideas below.

Could you...

- ...store the files in a PHAR archive?
- ...convert 10-20 images at a time to strings and "shoving" them into a file, as, perhaps, a serialized array?
- ...store 10-20 images as a single large file and read out just the part that we need, given that we know the size of each image in this "container"?

I realize this is kind of a stupid question, since none of these ideas are good ideas. But I want to know if it's POSSIBLE to solve this in any other way than changing web host or uploading the images to a third party.

Thanks!

Comment: Start using something like Amazon S3 for file storage. It's inexpensive and scales.

Comment: That's the workaround - I've actually already started the upload of the files to S3. But this question is not about that. :)

Comment: Time to upgrade to a CDN

Comment: @MadMarvin I think your workaround is better than the solution you are trying to achieve

Comment: You mention images, potentially you could store them as a base64 encoded string in a database, and then serve them up with PHP.

Comment: Is the web host issue the fact that there are that many images in a single folder? If so, you can just break them out into a bunch of sub folders by date or some other categorization.

Comment: I don't know what type of images you want to save or how do you plan on using them, but you could save them as sprites. Ex. save 20 images in a larger image and access them using their pixel offset. A good example is CSS sprites.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.phardata.php

Comment: @JeremyHarris The images are already in 10,000 subfolders (not 1000 as I wrote earlier). This does not matter, according to the host.

Comment: Sure you can use PHAR / ZIP but everytime someone need one img you need to unzip and get the img it's a bit heavy for the server.

Maybe take a second server only for img storage or AWS S3 is fast and more reliable